# Парсинг текстового файла, записанного в виде списка кортежей

Tags: python, list, input, tuple

На вход подается текстовый файл, который содержит список из трех списков с кортежами.

```
[ [(3, 5)], [((2, 2), 1)], [((3, 2), 1), ((2, 2), 2)] ]
```

На выходе нужен питоновский питоновский список кортежей

Я написала код, который справляется с задачей, но он мне кажется слишком "костыльным"

```py
f = open('input.txt','r', encoding='utf8')

#парсинг текстового файла записанного в виде списка кортежей
k = f.read().replace(' ', '').strip('[[ ]]\n').split('],[')
#вывод для демонтсрации того, что все работает чисто
for i in k:
    print(i)
#парсинг в три списка с целыми значениями
my_list1 = list(map(int, k[0].strip('( )').split(',')))
tmp = k[1].strip('( )').split('),((')
my_list2 = [ tuple(map(int, i.replace(')', '').split(','))) for i in tmp]
tmp = k[2].strip('( )').split('),((')
my_list3 = [ tuple(map(int, i.replace(')', '').split(','))) for i in tmp]
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки или методы, которые выполняют эту задачу?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Напишите чётко. Что на входе - текстовый файл? Так и пишите. Что должно быть на выходе? Список питона, в который разобран этот текст из файла, я правильно понял?

Comment: И ещё - что там насчёт форматирования, какой результат нужно получить, почему у вас слово "форматирование" в вопросе стоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот здесь](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) посмотрите

```py
>>> from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple

>>> for i in k:  
...   print(make_tuple(i)) 
(3, 5)
((2, 2), 1)
(((3, 2), 1), ((2, 2), 2))
```

на выходе будут кортежи, которые можно в лист

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно всё понял, то используйте `literal_eval`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

lst = literal_eval("[ [(3, 5)], [((2, 2), 1)], [((3, 2), 1), ((2, 2), 2)] ]")
print(type(lst), lst)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'list'> [[(3, 5)], [((2, 2), 1)], [((3, 2), 1), ((2, 2), 2)]]
```

Comment: На скорость) + )

Comment: @Dmitry Да, хотя на входе там чисто текст всё-таки, и не надо делать `as` при импорте, если это не какой-то стандартный вариант упрощающий понимание )

Comment: пытаюсь максимально доходчиво) этот вариант без обработки в переменную `k` приятнее.